# Is pyramid_who (repoze.who) the preferred way to do authentication for pyramid?

Tags: python, authentication, pyramid, repoze.who

I am just starting to learn [Pyramid Framework](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid.html). Is pyramid_who (repoze.who) the preferred way to do authentication?

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

pyramid_who is the best way to utilize repoze.who v2 for doing authentication. Whether this is the best authentication solution for you or not is dependent on your needs.

Typically repoze.who is the best solution for doing SSO (single sign-on) solutions where you need to connect to a service like LDAP.

If SSO is not a requirement, it is typically very simple to either use the pre-baked authentication solutions in pyramid such as AuthTkt, or to implement your own authentication policy.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to write my own since it is so simple, but there are a couple other options.

Here is a nice tutorial on how pyramid authentication works, [tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/authorization.html).